# upload image and doc in different folders on form submit in php codeignatior

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a form with four fileds like contactemail,contactname,category,comments as of now now i have to add image and doc input in a form,using form i have inserted data to db,how to upload image and doc in codeignatior on form submit

images need to upload in image folder and doc in docs folder
Here is my controller

```
public function form() {

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $data = $this->login_model->form();
//loading views
load-view-header
load view page
load-view-footer

}
```

here my model function

```
  public function form() {
        $contactemail = $this->input->post('contactemail');
        $contactname = $this->input->post('contactname');
        $category = $this->input->post('category');
        $comments = $this->input->post('comments');

        $data = array(
            'contactemail' => $email,
            'contactname' => $name,
            'category' => $category,
            'comments' => $comments
        );
        $this->db->insert('contact', $data);
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.  This was put together quickly and is completely untested...at best there may be errors and at worst memory has failed me and I totally missed something but may be a useful example.  Let me know if it helps?

View:

```
<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<!-- your other form fields  for email, name, category, comments can go here-->
<input type="file" name="image" size="20" />
<input type="file" name="doc" size="20" />
<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Controller:

```
    function form()
    {
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $data['error'] = "";


            //it would be good to be using the form validation class but here is a quick and dirty check for the submit

            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
                {
                        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
                else
                {
                        $image_upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                }

                unset($config);
                $config['upload_path'] = './docs/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|txt';
                $config['max_size'] = '2048';

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('doc'))
                {
                        $data['error'] .= "<br />".$this->upload->display_errors();

                }
                else
                {
                        $doc_upload_data = $this->upload->data();

                }




                if(!empty($data['error']))
                {
                     $this->load->view('form', $data);
                }
                else
                {
                      $contactemail = $this->input->post('contactemail');
                      $contactname = $this->input->post('contactname');
                      $category = $this->input->post('category');
                      $comments = $this->input->post('comments');
                      $doc_file = $doc_upload_data['full_path'];
                      $image_file = $image_upload_data['full_path'];

                      $form_data = array(
                      'contactemail' => $email,
                      'contactname' => $name,
                      'category' => $category,
                      'comments' => $comments,
                      'doc_file' => $doc_file
                  );


                      $image_data['image_name'] = $image_file;
                      $this->login_model->form($form_data,$image_data);

                      $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('form', $data);
            }
}
```

Model

```
public function form($form_data,$image_data) {

        $this->db->insert('contact', $image_data);

        $image_data['d_fk']  = $this->db->insert_id();

        $this->db->insert('images', $image_data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks henry for the reply,as i am new to code ignatior,need a suggestion how to do if the doc need to inserted in one table and images in images table eg: 1)images table have id_fk colum and image name colum and 2)form table will wi have id and all the fileds insertion except image based on last inserted id,i need to inserted image in images table, can you suggest?

Comment: see my edit, this assumes you are inserting the file path and name and storing the file in the file system